# Access control template property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following control template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GlassButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="Timeline1">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="glow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="Timeline2">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="glow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4">
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="#7F0000" BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.507*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.493*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="glow" Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.702" ScaleY="2.243"/>
                                        <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="-0.368" Y="-0.152"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Color="#B28DBDFF" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#008DBDFF" Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="shine" Width="Auto" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.494,0.889" StartPoint="0.494,0.028">
                                <GradientStop Color="#99FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#33FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="shine" Value="0.4"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#CC000000"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="glow" Value="Hidden"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Timeline1}"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Timeline2_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Timeline2}"/>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Now, I want to apply this template to a number of different buttons.  However, I would like the background color to be different for each button.  The property of the control template I am looking to change for each button is the background of the border

```
<Border x:Name="border" Background="#7F0000">
```

I need to be able to set different values for that background.  Setting it like

```
<Button Background="Yellow" Template="{DynamicResource GlassButton}">
```

doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `Border` element to which you want to apply the background, bind it as follows:

```
<Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"...
```

Comment: Great, that works like a charm.  On a related note, is it possible to do something similar with the gradient stop colors of the glow and shine borders?  I mean, is that something that can also be controlled from the individual buttons that this template is applied to?

Comment: The gradient stops etc. are basically another brush that you wish to use on another element in your template (other than that border we already saw). Since you don't have two `Background` properties on a `Button` there's no available brush type property to bind that other element's background to. You'll need to create a custom control derived from a button for that, and declare a few extra dependency properties.